# Access a field from $addFields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I use MongoDB aggregate and want to use fields that I added with $addFields to make for example a calculation. Is that somehow possible? Without $project would be best.

```
Post.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "id" },
  { $addField: {
      first: 5,
      second: 10,
      third: { $add: ["$first", "$second"] }
    } 
  } 
)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access those fields in the same pipeline stage (you can only refer to fields that are returned from previous pipeline stage), you have to do that in next stage:

```
Post.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: "id" },
    { 
        $addField: {
            first: 5,
            second: 10           
        } 
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            third: { $add: ["$first", "$second"] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Ah, I can use addField multiple times. That's great to know! Thanks.